# How to convert mongoDB shell query to php

Tags: php, mongodb

How to Convert mongoDB Query to php

```
db.getCollection('xyz').aggregate({ $match: { 
$and: [ 
{ created_at: { $gt:new ISODate("2016-07-05"), $lt:new ISODate("2016-09-05") }, id: "1" } 
] 
} }, 
{ $group: { _id : "distance", sum : { $sum: "$distance" } } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code below which used to connect mongodb with php.

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->yourDB;

$collection = $db->yourCollecton;

$sdate = '2016-01-01';
$sdate = '2016-01-31';

$pipeline = array(
    array(
        '$match'=>array('date'=>array('$gte'=>$sdate,'$lte'=>$edate))       
    ),
    array(
         '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(null),
            'first_field' => array('$field'),
          )
    )
);

$cursor = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
$row  = $cursor['result'][0];
```

Comment: I'm facing problem with "$match" array, Code is working without "$match"
**Problem with below code**
`array(
        '$match'=>array('date'=>array('$gte'=>$sdate,'$lte'=>$edate))       
    ),`

Comment: I am filtering the rows based on the $match condition